# DataGridView Source

Tags: c#, datagridview, objectdatasource

I have a class with three variables:

```
public class IO_ObjectMapping

{
    public String IOName = "";
    public String ObjectName = "";
    public String ObjectAttribute = "";
    public IO_ObjectMapping()
    {

    }
    public IO_ObjectMapping(String IOName, String ObjectName, String ObjectAttribute)
    {
        this.IOName = IOName;
        this.ObjectName = ObjectName;
        this.ObjectAttribute = ObjectAttribute;

    }

}
```

In my main class I create a  list of objects:

```
List<IO_ObjectMapping> lIO = new List<IO_ObjectMapping>();
```

Then add the objects:

```
        foreach (String item in IOs)
        {
            lIO.Add(new IO_ObjectMapping(item, "", ""));
        }
        foreach (String item in SCD_Objects)
        {
            lIO.Add(new IO_ObjectMapping("", item, ""));
        }
```

How can i populate a DataGridView where each row is one object with three cells?

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = data1;
```

Comment: Did you call `dataGridView1.DataBind()` after setting the data source?

Comment: Win Forms? Web Forms?

Comment: This is a windows forms application. No i did not, the object does not have that method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List` does not implement `IBindingList` , use `BindingList<T>` instead.

```
var bindingList = new BindingList<IO_ObjectMapping>(lIO);
//fill data
var source = new BindingSource(bindingList, null);
grid.DataSource = source;
```